# Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException : SQLite Error 1: 'dlopen(mod_spatialite.dylib, 0x000A): tried: 'mod_spatialite.dylib' (no such file),

Tags: .net, sqlite, entity-framework

When running test on Mac M series of chips. Im using rider test explorer to run the tests.

```
Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException : SQLite Error 1: 'dlopen(mod_spatialite.dylib, 0x000A): tried: 'mod_spatialite.dylib' (no such file), '/System/...
 
Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException : SQLite Error 1: 'dlopen(mod_spatialite.dylib, 0x000A): tried: 'mod_spatialite.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OSmod_spatialite.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/mod_spatialite.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache), 'mod_spatialite.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/mod_spatialite.dylib' (no such '.
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection.LoadExtensionCore(String file, String proc)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection.LoadExtension(String file, String proc)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.SpatialiteLoader.Load(DbConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Storage.Internal.SqliteRelationalConnection.InitializeDbConnection(DbConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Storage.Internal.SqliteRelationalConnection..ctor(RelationalConnectionDependencies dependencies, IRawSqlCommandBuilder rawSqlCommandBuilder, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
   at System.Reflection.ConstructorInvoker.Invoke(Object obj, IntPtr* args, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.SqliteServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c.<AddEntityFrameworkSqlite>b__1_0(IServiceProvider p)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
```

I have installed `libspatialite` which is expected to contain `mod_spatialite.dylib` but running the tests nothing worked. The solution is referred from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sqlite/spatial.

Answer (score 2):

Following the solution addressed by MS learn, was required to set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=` environment variable that shall be used when running the tests. So the steps I did are;

1. Installing `libspatialite` which I already did, if its not please do,
2. Chech DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH value by running on command `sh echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` [image]
3. Added DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH to Rider Test Runner environment variable [image]

4. That's all for now...